# How to most efficiently modify R / G / B values?

Tags: c++, optimization, rgb, pixel

So I wanted to implement lighting in my pixel based rendering system, googled and found out to display R / G / B values lighter or darker I have to multiply each red green and blue value by a number < 1 to display it darker and by a number > 1 to display it lighter.

So I implemented it like this, but its really dragging down my performance since I have to do this for each pixel:

```
void PixelRenderer::applyLight(Uint32& color){
    Uint32 alpha = color >> 24;
    alpha << 24;
    alpha >> 24;

    Uint32 red = color >> 16;
    red = red << 24;
    red = red >> 24;

    Uint32 green = color >> 8;
    green = green << 24;
    green = green >> 24;

    Uint32 blue = color;
    blue = blue << 24;
    blue = blue >> 24;

    red = red * 0.5;
    green = green * 0.5;
    blue = blue * 0.5;
    color = alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
}
```

Any ideas or examples on how to improve the speed?

Comment: if you just need `* 0.5`, you could do `(color>>1)&0x7f7f7f7f`.

Comment: yeah it works, and im doing this so i ONLY have the red value and not also the alpha value infront. And `*0.5` is just an example

Comment: @Wimmel: Probably need to retain the Alpha component properly.

Comment: You are right. this should keep alpha unchanged: `(color&0xff000000)|((color>>1)&0x007f7f7f)`

Comment: @Styxs: Are you SURE this code is causing something to be slow? What else are you doing in your code? How big a peak is this function in the overall performance profile?

Comment: At the very least, get rid of the floating-point multiplications by 0.5, and simply divide by 2. GCC is not able to optimise away the floating-point multiplication, because you *might* be relying on specific floating-point exceptions (which won't even happen).

Comment: (1) use bitmasks instead of shifts. (2) This will not work for values > 1, you need to clamp the values as well. (3) *All* per-pixel operations will be slow, with enough pixels.

Comment: Enable optimisations.

Comment: Ouch, you are passing through `double`s to divide an integer in half? No wonder it's slow... All the rest (bitmasks vs shifts & co) is nothing compared to the int->double and double->int casts (especially since the retarded "round towards zero" semantic requires a ridiculous amount of work on x87).

Comment: @MatteoItalia How would you recommend me to do it? Note that 0.5 is just an example and i might also need 0.2 or whatever.

Comment: Use a scaled integer (255=1, 0=0) and do integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Jongware Yeah i tested it and it doesnt work with values greater than 1, what do you mean with "clamp the values"?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I haven't heard of that before but i'll read up on it thanks.

And yeah i tried dividing by 2 instead of multiplying by 0.5 and it improved the performance greatly.

Comment: "Clamping" a value is to make sure it does not fall below or above certain values -- in your case, 0 and 255. A division can never make it go lower than 0 but after each multiplication you need to check the result is <= 255 (for each pixel *and* for each channel ... you may want to consider other methods).

Comment: @Jongware Yeah i see, thanks. Ill have to look for a workaround so i dont do this for every pixel

Comment: What is your hardware, compiler, compiler options (e.g. optimization level), and OS?

Comment: Hardware: Intel Core i5-3570K, 16GB RAM dunno if you need anything else. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 so the compiler that comes with that, i didn't modify the options and i'm using Windows 7 64Bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the alpha value in the front use:

```
(color>>1)&0x7F7F7F | (color&0xFF000000)
```

(A tweak on what Wimmel offered in the comments).

I think the 'learning curve' here is that you were using shift and shift back to mask out bits. You should use `&` with a masking value.

For a more general solution (where `0.0<=factor<=1.0`) :

```
void PixelRenderer::applyLight(Uint32& color, double factor){
    Uint32 alpha=color&0xFF000000;
    Uint32 red=  (color&0x00FF0000)*factor;
    Uint32 green= (color&0x0000FF00)*factor;
    Uint32 blue=(color&0x000000FF)*factor;

   color=alpha|(red&0x00FF0000)|(green&0x0000FF00)|(blue&0x000000FF);
}
```

Notice there is no need to shift the components down to the low order bits before performing the multiplication.

Ultimately you may find that the bottleneck is floating point conversions and arithmetic.

To reduce that you should consider either:

1. Reduce it to a scaling factor for example in the range 0-256.
2. Precompute `factor*component` as a 256 element array and 'pick' the components out oft.

I'm proposing a range of 257 because you can achieve the factor as follows:

For a more general solution (where `0<=factor<=256`) :

```
void PixelRenderer::applyLight(Uint32& color, Uint32 factor){
    Uint32 alpha=color&0xFF000000;
    Uint32 red=  ((color&0x00FF0000)*factor)>>8;
    Uint32 green= ((color&0x0000FF00)*factor)>>8;
    Uint32 blue=((color&0x000000FF)*factor)>>8;

    color=alpha|(red&0x00FF0000)|(green&0x0000FF00)|(blue&0x000000FF);
}
```

---

Here's a runnable program illustrating the first example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef uint32_t Uint32;

Uint32 make(Uint32 alpha,Uint32 red,Uint32 green,Uint32 blue){
    return (alpha<<24)|(red<<16)|(green<<8)|blue;
}

void output(Uint32 color){
    printf("alpha=%"PRIu32" red=%"PRIu32" green=%"PRIu32" blue=%"PRIu32"\n",(color>>24),(color&0xFF0000)>>16,(color&0xFF00)>>8,color&0xFF);
}

Uint32 applyLight(Uint32 color, double factor){
    Uint32 alpha=color&0xFF000000;
    Uint32 red=  (color&0x00FF0000)*factor;
    Uint32 green= (color&0x0000FF00)*factor;
    Uint32 blue=(color&0x000000FF)*factor;

    return alpha|(red&0x00FF0000)|(green&0x0000FF00)|(blue&0x000000FF);
}

int main(void) {
    Uint32 color1=make(156,100,50,20);
    Uint32 result1=applyLight(color1,0.9);
    output(result1);

    Uint32 color2=make(255,255,255,255);
    Uint32 result2=applyLight(color2,0.1);
    output(result2);

    Uint32 color3=make(78,220,200,100);
    Uint32 result3=applyLight(color3,0.05);
    output(result3);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output is:

```
alpha=156 red=90 green=45 blue=18
alpha=255 red=25 green=25 blue=25
alpha=78 red=11 green=10 blue=5
```

Comment: This could be useful, but the OP said `* 0.5` is just an example.

Comment: Your code for example: `Uint32 red = color&0x00FF0000);` doesn't work.
If i use it like that without even modifying any values i just get a yellow screen.

Comment: @Styxs: Odd. You did notice I was returning a value from `void`. That should just be a compile error. Try the runnable example I've added at the bottom of the answer. It works for me.

Comment: Your example program works just fine, however when i try to integrate your `applyLight` function i always get 0 for the red green and blue values which results in a color value of 0xFF000000

Comment: @Styxs: So what value of `factor` are you using? Try posting another question if you need help integrating the code. Try to provide an MCVE. We're now in a conversation where the only code we can both see works.

Comment: Nevermind, my parameter was still an unsigned int instead of a double..
But anyways it seems like the multiplication with the double is really slow anyways. So i'll just be using your other example in which you used integers as the factor. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Note that this won't work reliably for factors > 1.0 (to make the image brighter). You need to clip your values at 255 for that (this will introduce some branches which will slow things down).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: (EDIT: as it turns out, this is only a readability improvement, but read on for more insights.)

```
void PixelRenderer::applyLight(Uint32& color)
{
    Uint32 alpha = color >> 24;
    Uint32 red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
    Uint32 green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
    Uint32 blue = color & 0xff;
    red = red * 0.5;
    green = green * 0.5;
    blue = blue * 0.5;
    color = alpha << 24 | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
}
```

That having been said, you should understand that performing operations of that sort using a general-purpose processor such as the CPU of your computer is bound to be extremely slow.  That's why hardware-accelerated graphics cards were invented.

EDIT

If you insist on operating this way, then you will probably have to resort to hacks in order to improve efficiency.  One type of hack which is very often used when dealing with 8-bit channel values is lookup tables.  With a lookup table, instead of multiplying each individual channel value by a float, you precompute an array of 256 values where the index into the array is a channel value, and the value in that index is the precomputed result of multiplying the channel value by that float.  Then, when converting your image, you just use channel values to lookup entries of the array instead of performing actual float multiplication.  This is much, much faster.  (But still not nearly as fast as programming dedicated, massively parallel hardware do that stuff for you.)

EDIT

As others have already pointed out, if you are not planning to operate on the alpha channel, then you do not need to extract it and then later apply it, you can just leave it unaltered.  So, you can just do `color = (color & 0xff000000) | red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;`

Comment: If you'd read the comments before answering, you'd have already seen that this answer just isn't useful...

Comment: @hvd Hmm, actually, look: he says that 0.5 is just an example.  So he needs a general purpose algorithm, which means that my answer might actually the best so far.

Comment: I realise that (and already pointed that out on another answer). But even then, the transformation that you've made is one that compilers are already capable of making themselves, so you don't really improve the performance, just the readability. Still, I'll withdraw my downvote, in hindsight I don't think it's a bad answer, just not a good one (yet).

Comment: So there's no performance improvement possible apart from not assigning this to every pixel?

Comment: @Styxs Testing with GCC 4.9.2 and compiling with `-march=native -O3`, I get identical machine code for the code in your question and the code in this answer.

Comment: @hvd okay, I think my latest edit should satisfy you.

Comment: @MikeNakis Heh, creative. Whether it's good depends on how the OP will be using this: it may be good if many calculations are made with the exact same factor, but not so good if the factor often varies (which requires re-calculating the lookup table). I do like it. :)

Comment: @hvd Actually, it can be very good even if the lookup table needs to be calculated prior to each and every operation on the image. If you are to process a 1920x1050 image you are looking at 256 float multiplications versus six million of them.

Comment: @MikeNakis Yeah, but that assumes the whole image should be modified by the same factor. The OP is implementing lighting in a rendering system, which suggests to me that that assumption doesn't hold.

Comment: There's no need to 'shift down and back' to perform the multiplications. It can all be achieved with masking. Remember shift multiply and shift back is the same as multiply (give or take the fractional part and overflow).

Answer (score 3):

Shifts and masks like this are generally very fast on a modern processor. I might look at a few other things:

1. Follow the first rule of optimisation - profile your code. You can do this simply by calling the method millions of times and timing it. Are your calculations slow, or is it something else? What is slow? Try omitting part of the method - do things speed up?
2. Make sure that this function is declared inline (and make sure it has actually been inlined). The function call overhead will massively outweigh the pixel manipulations (particularly if it is virtual).
3. Consider declaring your method `Uint32 PixelRenderer::applyLight(Uint32 color)` and returning the modified value, that may help avoid some dereferences and give the compiler some additional optimisation opportunities.
4. Avoid fp to integer conversions, they can be very expensive. If a plain integer divide is insufficient, look at using fixed-point math.

Finally, look at the assembler to see what the compiler has generated (with optimisations on). Are there any branches or conversions? Has your method actually been inlined?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I don't see anyone else mentioning is parallelizing your code. There are at least 2 ways to do this: SIMD instructions, and multiple threads.

[SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (like SSE, AVX, etc.) perform the same math on multiple pieces of data at the same time. So you could, for example, multiply the red, green, blue, and alpha of a pixel by the same values in 1 instruction, like this:

```
vec4 lightValue = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
vec4 result = vec_Mult(inputPixel, lightValue);
```

That's the equivalent of:

```
lightValue.red = 0.5;
lightValue.green = 0.5;
lightValue.blue = 0.5;
lightValue.alpha = 1.0;

result.red = inputPixel.red * lightValue.red;
result.green = inputPixel.green * lightValue.green;
result.blue = inputPixel.blue * lightValue.blue;
result.alpha = inputPixel.alpha * lightValue.alpha;
```

You can also cut your image into tiles and perform the lightening operation on several tiles at once using threads run on multiple cores. If you're using C++11, you can use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) to start multiple threads. Otherwise your OS probably has functionality for threading, such as [WinThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx), [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html), [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads), [boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread.html), [Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org), etc.

You can combine both of the above and have multithreaded code that operates on whole pixels at a time.

If you want to take it even further, you can do your processing on the GPU of your machine using [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org), [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/), [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35), [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/), [Mantle](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/mantle#overview), [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html), or one of the other [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) technologies. GPUs are generally hundreds of cores that can very quickly process many tiles in parallel, each of which processes whole pixels (rather than just channels) at a time.

But an even better option may be not to write any code at all. It's extremely likely that someone has already done this work and you can leverage it. For example, on MacOS there's [CoreImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) and the [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) framework. On iOS you also have CoreImage, and there's also [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). I'm sure there are similar libraries on Windows, Linux, and other OSes you might be working with.

Comment: I don't really understand how i would implement that "SIMD" instruction or what even that example does.

Comment: You wouldn't implement the SIMD instruction. Your process likely already has something like it built-in. I apologize for being a little vague in my example. You didn't specify a platform, and SIMD instructions are not very portable, so I wrote it as pseudo-code. All it does is multiply the `lightValue` (red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1.0) by the `inputPixel`. So it should do something similar to what you specified in your example.

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain it better and provided some links to other tools.

Comment: Yeah i might consider reprogramming it all on OpenGL, but i don't really have the time to learn OpenGL right now.

Answer (score 1):

- Another solution without using bit shifters, is to convert your `32 bits uint` into a `struct`.
- Try to keep your implementation in the `.h` include file, so that it can be inlined
- If you don't want to have the implementation inlined (see above), modify your `applyLight` method to accept an array of pixels. Method call overhead can be significant for such a small method
- Enable "loop unroll" optimisation on your compiler, which will enable the usage of SIMD instructions

Implementation:

```
class brightness {
private:
    struct pixel { uint8_t b, g, r, a; };
    float factor;

    static inline void apply(uint8_t& p, float f) {
        p = max(min(int(p * f), 255),0);
    }

public:
    brightness(float factor) : factor(factor) { }

    void apply(uint32_t& color){
        pixel& p = (pixel&)color;

        apply(p.b, factor);
        apply(p.g, factor);
        apply(p.r, factor);
    }
};
```

Implementation with a lookup table (slower when you use "loop unroll"):

```
class brightness {

    struct pixel { uint8_t b, g, r, a; };

    uint8_t table[256];

public:
    brightness(float factor) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            table[i] = max(min(int(i * factor), 255), 0);
    }

    void apply(uint32_t& color){
        pixel& p = (pixel&)color;

        p.b = table[p.b];
        p.g = table[p.g];
        p.r = table[p.r];
    }
};




// usage
brightness half_bright(0.5);
uint32_t pixel = 0xffffffff;
half_bright.apply(pixel);
```